# How to display multiple data sets in Symfony2

Tags: database, symfony, twig

I am totally new to Symfony and i d like to know how I manage to display multiple data sets from my db in a twig...
untill now my attempt is the following:

```
class ProjController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_projekte")
     * @Template("FHBingenBundle:projekte:list.html.twig")
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    { 

 $projekte = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('FHBingenBundle:Projekt')->findAll();
        return $projekte;
    }
}
```

to get all the data sets. Here is where my Problem starts... how do I extract the data from the array? (the entity has multiple columns but i only want two of them, name and description)

```
{% extends "FHBingenBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

    {% block content %}
       <table>
        <?php foreach ($liste as $projekt ?>
           <tr><p>{{ $projekt->getName() }}</p></tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
       </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

thats how I tried to do it but apperently I am not allowed to use $ inside of {{}}? atleast thats what the error says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider reading the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html).

Since you are using twig, think about using twig templating system.

```
{% for item in navigation %} // equivalent to foreach($navigation as $item) {
    {{ item.name }} // equivalent to $item->name or $item->getName() or $item->hasName()
{% endfor %} // equivalent to }
```

EDIT : I don't really remember but it seems that you have to return an array for the twig templating system. `return array('projects' => $projects);`

Comment: You're right about the array returned by the controller. It must be :
`[$variableName => $variableValue]`.
Here the `for` loop documentation : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html